# With Ionic 2 how do you change a button based on login status through a modal that sends you to another page after you login?

Tags: javascript, angular, authentication, ionic2, modalviewcontroller

I have a button on my home page that should say 'Log out' when the user is logged in and 'Log in' when no user is logged in. The login button opens a modal. Once the user logs in, it sends them to a different page. When the user navigates back to home page while logged in, the button should now say 'Log out'.

I've tried all of the ionView life cycle events from the NavController.

I think it could have something to do with creating a two-bound variable but as of now I'm unsure how to do that for this case.

I also think there may be some way to emit data via the NavController or ViewController back to the home page. I'm not sure if this is a viable solution either or how to execute this at this time.

Finally I think if I could return a value through the openModal function in the Home page should the user login from the login modal that could work too but again, I'm not clear as to how to make that happen.

Code for Page Home page:

home.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, ModalController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { LoginService } from '../../services/loginService';
import { Login } from '../login/login';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html',
  providers: [LoginService]
})
export class Home {
  person: any;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public storage: Storage, public loginService: LoginService, public benefitService: MembershipBenefitService, public modalCtrl: ModalController) {
    this.benefit = benefitService.benefit(Parse.User.current());
    this.person = Parse.User.current();console.log("this.person", this.person);
  }

openModal(): any{
    let profileModal = this.modalCtrl.create(Login);
    profileModal.present();        
  }

  signout(): any{
    this.loginService.logout();
    this.person = null;
    return this.person
  }
```

home.html

```
<ion-header class="opaque">
  <ion-navbar align-title=”center”>
    <br>
    <ion-title>
      <img src="assets/new-logo-sm.png"/>
    </ion-title>
    <ion-buttons end>
      <button ion-button icon-only *ngIf="person != null" (click)="signout()">
        Sign out
      </button>
      <button ion-button icon-only *ngIf="person == null" (click)="openModal()">
        <ion-icon name="help-circle"></ion-icon>
      </button>
    </ion-buttons>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
```

Code for Modal:

login.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Parse } from 'parse-js-sdk';

import { LoginService } from '../../services/loginService';



@Component({
  selector: 'login',
  templateUrl: 'login.html',
  providers: [LoginService]
})

export class Login {
  email: string = "";
  password: string = "";
  person: any;
  personEmail: any;


  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private loginService: LoginService) {
    var self = this;
    self.person = Parse.User.current()//.get("email");
    console.log('self.person', self.person);
    if(self.person !== null){
      self.personEmail = Parse.User.current().id
    }
  }

login(){
    this.loginService.login(this.email, this.password);
  }
}
```

login.html

```
  <form (ngSubmit)="login()">
    <ion-list class="clearbackground">
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label floating class="input-label">Email Address</ion-label>
        <ion-input class="input-label" [(ngModel)]="email" required="required" type="email" maxlength="200" name="email"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
      <br>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label floating class="input-label">Password</ion-label>
        <ion-input [(ngModel)]="password" required="required" type="password" maxlength="200" name="password"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
      <br>          
    </ion-list>
  </form>

  <ion-list>
    <ion-grid>
      <ion-row>
        <ion-col>
          <button class="login-button-two" (click)="login()">Welcome Back</button>
          <br>
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
    </ion-grid>
  </ion-list>
```

Login Service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AlertController, NavController, ViewController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Parse } from 'parse-js-sdk';
import { Directory } from '../pages/directory/directory';

@Injectable()
export class LoginService {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public alertCtrl: AlertController, public viewCtrl: ViewController) {
  }
login(email, password) {
  var self = this;
    if(Parse.User.current() === null) {
      return Parse.User.logIn(email, password, {
        success: function (logIn1User) {
          console.log('3', logIn1User);
          if(logIn1User.get("accountCanceled") === true){
            Parse.User.logOut();
            return self.accountCanceled();
          } else {
            self.navCtrl.push(Directory);
            self.viewCtrl.dismiss();
          }
        },
        error: function (logIn1User, error) {
          console.log('4', logIn1User, error);
          return self.emailMistake();
        }
      });

    } else {
      self.alreadyLoggedInMessage();
    }
  };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see the full plunker here http://plnkr.co/edit/jYDroF?p=preview, I used BehaviorSubject so then you can subscribe to changes to get the updates you need

excerpts from home.page.html

```
<ion-content padding>
  Welcome to this
  <ion-icon name="ionic"></ion-icon> <b>Ionic 2 app</b>
  <div>
    <button ion-button (click)="doLoginAction()" [disabled]="currentUser"> LOGIN </button>
    <button ion-button (click)="doLogoutAction()"  [disabled]="!currentUser"> LOGOUT </button>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>
    LOGIN STATUS <span *ngIf="currentUser">{{currentUser | json}}</span>
    </p>
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

home.page.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Authentication } from './auth';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'app/home.page.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  appName = 'Ionic App';
  currentUser

  constructor(public navController: NavController, public auth : Authentication) { 

    this.auth.activeUser.subscribe((_user)=>{
      this.currentUser = _user
    })
  }

  doLoginAction() {
    this.auth.doLogin();  
  }

  doLogoutAction() {
    this.auth.doLogout();
  }

}
```

auth.ts

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core'
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject'

@Injectable()
export class Authentication {

  activeUser = new BehaviorSubject(null)

  constructor() {

  }

  doLogin() {
    this.activeUser.next({ username: 'aaron@mail.com'})
  }

  doLogout() {
     this.activeUser.next(null)   
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your service:

```
user_status = false;
get_user_status() {
    return this.user_status;
}
set_user_status(user_status) {
    this.user_status = user_status;
}

login() {
    //some task
    this.user_status = true;
}

signout() {
    //some task
    this.user_status = false;
}
```

In your .ts file:

```
get_user_status(){
   return this.LoginService.get_user_status();
}

login(){
  this.LoginService.login();
}

signout(){
  this.LoginService.signout();
}
```

and finally in you .html file:

```
<ion-buttons end>
        <button ion-button icon-only *ngIf="get_user_status()" (click)="signout()">
    Sign out
  </button>
        <button ion-button icon-only *ngIf="!get_user_status()" (click)="login()">
    <ion-icon name="help-circle"></ion-icon>
  </button>
    </ion-buttons>
```

Comment: I really appreciate your response and it looks like it should work but it doesn't. Additionally I tried a few variation on your suggestion like putting loginService.get_user_status() in the ts constructor, and set_user_status in the service in the login and signout functions after reassigning user_status to true or false. I think there is a scope challenge with my query. It always returns a promise and since it's the A+ promise library I can't get the result separate from the scope of the promise.

Comment: I test the code and it's work fine. it don't depend on your query. first use my solution without 'login(email, password)' and then add your logic. also add loginService to src/app/app.module.ts providers not in your login component.

Comment: I'm not clear as to what you mean re:  'login(email, password)'. Also, I have the LoginService in my app.module.ts providers. Given the documentation I've seen we should not need to include a provider in the component but when I don't include it I get a  "No provider for NavController!" error. For whatever reason I noticed that I needed to also inject in the component. Perhaps I'm doing something else wrong?

Ok I think I may understand the misunderstanding. I have to know if the user logged in successfully before I can change the login status and this is a promise.

Answer (score 0):

I used the explanation from: 
https://ionicallyspeaking.com/2016/03/05/publishing-and-subscribing-to-events-in-ionic-2/

Which references subscribing and publishing to Angular Events.

The new LoginService:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AlertController, NavController, ViewController, Events } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Parse } from 'parse-js-sdk';
import { Directory } from '../pages/directory/directory';

@Injectable()
export class LoginService {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public alertCtrl: AlertController, public viewCtrl: ViewController, public events: Events) {}

  sendUserStatus(userStatus) {
    this.events.publish('loginStatus',userStatus);
  }

login(email, password) {
  var self = this;
    if(Parse.User.current() === null) {
      return Parse.User.logIn(email, password, {
        success: function (logIn1User) {
          console.log('3', logIn1User);
          if(logIn1User.get("accountCanceled") === true){
            Parse.User.logOut();
            return self.accountCanceled();
          } else {
            self.userStatus = true;
            self.sendUserStatus(self.userStatus);
            self.navCtrl.push(Directory);
            self.viewCtrl.dismiss();
          }
        },
        error: function (logIn1User, error) {
          console.log('4', logIn1User, error);
          return self.emailMistake();
        }
      });

    } else {
      self.alreadyLoggedInMessage();
    }
  };
}
```

The new home.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, ModalController, Events } from 'ionic-angular';
import { LoginService } from '../../services/loginService';
import { Login } from '../login/login';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html',
  providers: [LoginService]
})
export class Home {
  person: any;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public storage: Storage, public loginService: LoginService, public benefitService: MembershipBenefitService, public modalCtrl: ModalController, public events: Events) {
    this.benefit = benefitService.benefit(Parse.User.current());
    this.listenToLoginEvents();
  }

openModal(): any{
    let profileModal = this.modalCtrl.create(Login);
    profileModal.present();        
  }

  signout(): any{
    this.loginService.logout();
    this.person = null;
    return this.person
  }

listenToLoginEvents() {
    this.events.subscribe('loginStatus', (status) => {
      this.person = status;
    });
  }

}
```